# Как сделать авторизацию без регистрации NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, регистрация

Я решил написать свой блог, пишу бекенд на NodeJs + mongoDB. Авторизации как таковой на сайте не предусмотрено, но должен быть админ у которого есть право удалять, изменять записи.
Возник вопрос как реализовать авторизацию без регистрации, тоесть будет api с запросом на авторизацию, но не будет api с регистрацией (чтобы случайный пользователь не мог зарегистрироваться) или он будет но как ограничить доступ? Можно ли записать админа напрямую в бд и заходить с помощью логина и пароля? Как правильно реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете создать учетную запись в БД, напрямую задав необходимые параметры для дальнейшего доступа.

Если вопрос безопасности не очень актуален для вашего проекта, захэшируйте пароль (как это правильно сделать - в интернете есть много информации) и пользуйтесь им. Но тогда, зная комбинацию логина и пароля можно будет раз и навсегда получить доступ к вашей записи.

С точки зрения безопасности и правильности, стоит сделать полноценную авторизацию. Для простоты воспользуйтесь обычным [JWT токеном](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token), время от времени проверяя его валидность. Затем, при желании, можете добавить рефреш-токен.

Таким образом, если вы уверены на 100%, что никто и никогда не будет пытаться взломать вашу учетную запись, создайте обычную запись типа логин/пароль. Но по-хорошему, а также в целях опыта, стоит сделать полноценный механизм.

По итогу у вас будет всего один пользователь и связанный с ним API авторизации.